# Concatenar una letra al insertar MYSQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tengo una tabla de reportes, en la cual quiero concatenar un `CQ-` en un campo `registro` al insertar datos. Para ello estoy intentando utilizar un trigger en MYQL, pero sigue fallando. Ya que inserto datos pero mi campo de registo aparece como 0. Este es el query

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER concat_CQ BEFORE INSERT ON
    reportes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE aux INT;
    SET aux = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'datos' AND TABLE_NAME = 'reportes');
    SET NEW.registro = CONCAT('CQ-', LPAD(aux, 8, '0'));
END//
DELIMITER;
```

El objetivo es que si se inserta un dato con id 1, el campo registro tenga CQ-1 tambien y asi sucesivamente con todos los datos.

Comment: No estas asignando valor a la variable aux, no debería ser `SET aux  = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM ...`

Comment: Ahora me aparece como 0, el campo registro

Comment: ¿Y no sería mas simple concatenar el nuevo id con la cadena de texto que quieres?

Comment: mmm ¿has intentado controlar el nuevo id por consulta? 
`SET aux = (SELECT MAX(id) /*campo autoincrementable*/ FROM reportes)+1;
 SET NEW.registro = CONCAT('CQ-', LPAD(aux, 8, '0'));`

Comment: @AbrahamChan pero eso no sigue lo que el OP busca ya que según leo el quiere concatenar el id del registro en proceso, no el id máximo que ya existe

Comment: @AbrahamChan ya lo solucione

Answer (score 0):

Al final simplemente coloque el CONCAT('CQ-'), tambien me di cuenta de que el campo registro no era de tipo Varchar sino INT

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER concat_CQ BEFORE INSERT ON pqr FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE aux INT;
    SET aux =( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'datos' AND TABLE_NAME = 'reportes');
    SET NEW.registro = CONCAT('CQ-', aux);
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```